# How to find the routing table of a zigbee sensor

Tags: routes, sensors, zigbee

I dont have much experience in the zibgee world. I want to find the routing table/path of the wireless sensor I use.

Setup: 
I have a door/window sensor MCT-320 and an outlet controller 4257050-RZHAC
paired to a touchscreen tca203.

I want to check whether the sensor is routing through the outlet controller or not for which i have to find the routing table. Please help me know about that. 
Also help with some links to learn the home security systems, protocols and its working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Zigbee stack/API you can issue a ZDO "NetworkAddressRequest" packet using the IEEE address of the sensor.  When the response comes back, the packet data will tell you the nodeId of the sensor.  You can look at the nodeId that issued the "NetworkAddressResponse" which will be the parent of the sensor